# Unable to connect to a local MYSQL server on wireles LAN

Tags: mysql, local-area-network, connection, wifi

Ok, Here is the technical description.
My laptop's config:
Ip Adress:192.168.2.5
Mysqlserver 5.0 on port : 3306
Operating system: Ubuntu jaunty (9.04)
3306 is open for both incoming and outgoing.

My friend's laptop config:
Ip Adress:192.168.2.4
Mysqlserver 5.0 on port : 3306
Operating system: Windows XP pro
3306 is open for both incoming and outgoing.

Both are on a wireless LAN connected through a belkin router (192.168.2.1)

Both the MYSQL servers have been given the sufficient GRANT privileges. I am also able to connect from 192.168.2.4 to 192.168.2.5's MYSQL instance but the vice versa is not happening. I am getting an (100061) error. Tried Telnetting on 3306; again happening from 192.168.2.4 to 192.168.2.5 but not the vice versa. Am I doing something wrong?
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Exact error messages would be helpful; also, your claims that the grants and firewalls are all correct don't carry much weight, and they're the most likely causes of problems.  Show that configuration, so we can check it for ourselves.

Comment: Some Belkin WiFi Routers implement Wireless Isolation - can you ping the two systems from each other? If not I'd say this is possibly a factor. You say you tried Telnetting but didn't say what the result was, I assume it failed? Also the Belkin router model would help.

Comment: @womble-Thanks for the response. Let me know exactly which outputs you need. I'll post them here. The GRANT command i executed on (192.168.2.4) is as follows: GRANT SELECT ON . TO root@192.168.2.5 IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; Since they are DEV systems user name and passwords are both root Then flush priviledges

Comment: @Helvick-The Belkin router has the model no. F5D7230. Firmware version F5D7230-4_UK_8.01.07. Yes i can ping both the systems from each other. I am not satisfied with the isolation argument as i am able to connect from 192.168.2.4 to 192.168.2.5. Problem when trying to connect the other way.

Answer (score 2):

most likely Mysql on Jaunty does not listen for external addresses or is not configured to accept connections from external addresses.

Can you telnet 192.168.2.4 3306 port from your Jaunty laptop?

You should check /etc/mysql/my.cnf bind-address variable and make sure to comment it out as well as skip-networking.

```
#skip-networking
#bind-address
```

Or bind address to all network interfaces

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```